# How to convert a random length of list to dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I convert a random length of list to dataframe in pandas? A list containing items as such

```
[1,'ABC',100,2,'DEF',200,3,'PQR',300,4,'XYZ',400]
```

Comment: Resultant data frame should look like this C1=[1,2,3,4], C2=[ABC,DEF,PQR,XYZ], C3=[100,200,300,400]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need.

```
data = [1,'ABC',100,2,'DEF',200,3,'PQR',300,4,'XYZ',400]
df = pd.DataFrame([data[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(data), 3)], columns=["C1", "C2", "C3"])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   C1   C2   C3
0   1  ABC  100
1   2  DEF  200
2   3  PQR  300
3   4  XYZ  400
```